# Iphone, Core-plot : String DateTime to INT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

i'm making iphone app using Core-Plot Chart, but core-plot use x, y axis as a numbers, and i want to use x axis as a DateTime, i have read the way to do it, but how can i convert the String DateTime to int number, to use it in core-plot.

Example:

> 2012-07-16 10:20:25

Comment: have you tried passing seconds? i.e. NSTimeInterval?

Comment: nope but i think this way not include date it's only for time, i'm not sure.

Comment: date is nothing but a moment in time. Try it. Also don't forget to set style of the X-Axis Label

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have an array of NSDates as 'dates' in ascending order.Now, We will create array of NSTimeIntervals 'xValues' from it.

```
NSDate * lastDate = [dates objectAtIndex:0]; // first date
for (NSDate * todaysDate in dates)          
    NSTimeInterval lastDiff = [lastDate timeIntervalSinceNow]; // time Interval since first date
    NSTimeInterval todaysDiff = [todaysDate timeIntervalSinceNow];// time Interval since current date
    NSTimeInterval dateDiff = todaysDiff - lastDiff; // actual difference 
    [xValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dateDiff ]];
}
```

Now once you have this array, in you core plot code, where you are creating X-Axis, do something like this. Set 'labelFormatter' of x-axis as below

```
CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.majorIntervalLength = your call;
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = your call;
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 5;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"]; // you can have your date format
dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
CPTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[CPTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter] autorelease];
timeFormatter.referenceDate = some reference date;
x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;
```